# Orchard: creating a layer at content creation

Tags: orchardcms

In my Orchard website, I want to create blogs quickly, and for each of them I want to be able to add a blog archive widget to their page.

To achieve this, I have to create a new windget layer for each and every blog. Is it possible to make this process automatic without creating a custom module? I guess I can create a rule reacting to blog creation event, but can I have it execute a script for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a module, but there are several ways to go about it. Your rule idea is an interesting one, as it could be applied to any content item once you've built it. It should be fairly easy to build: you would just need to create a custom "Create Layer" Rule Action. You can look at existing rule actions for a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought, but I needed a confirmation.